# Drag-Drop and swap not working smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

I need to implement a drag drop and swap functionality in the portlet and their arrangement will be somewhat as shown in the figure.

1 2
3 4

This is a web application which will be run on iDevices as well. I tried doing it with a plugin called redplugin 
  http://www.redplugin.com/index.php?mainmenu=11&submenu=18
 Doing this worked great on for desktops but swap failed to work on my iPhone hence i added  jquery ui touch punch which resolved my problem to some extent. The transition isn't that smooth and the swap does not work when i drag drop them diagonally and doesnt work for all the possible ways, works only when portlet is dragged drop either from a row left-right or right-left(Works for drag 1-2,2-1,3-4,4-3 but not for 1-4,4-1,2-3,3-2,. Are there any other plugins which will help me achieve this purpose?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use jquery `drag` & `drop` here. Take a look at
this [JQFAQ.com](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-drag-and-drop-replace-the-position/), where it was discussed and resolved with an answer and there are more FAQs also available. Hope, this may help you.